# How to create a Dropwizard project with gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, dropwizard

I am on a Linux machine with Idea IntelliJ and I would like to create a Dropwizard project with gradle. With maven archetypes this job would be very easy.

```
mvn archetype:generate 
-DarchetypeGroupId=io.dropwizard.archetypes 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=java-simple 
-DarchetypeVersion=[REPLACE ME WITH A VALID DROPWIZARD VERSION]
```

For gradle I am struggling to get going. As I checked out other post I was wondering if what I did was correct:

```
// Needed Instead of the Shade plug in 
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.1'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
group 'org.example.sampleName'
description 'Sample Dropwizard REST '

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:1.2.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

mainClassName = 'org.example.sampleName.SampleApplication'

run {
    args = ['server', 'config.yml']
}

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA', 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF'

}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}
```

Then I just run `gradle shadowJar` and then run `java -jar build/SampleApplication.jar server config.yml`. Is this correct? And is the line `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` enough for the unit test?

Comment: I see you follow this blogpost https://automationrhapsody.com/build-dropwizard-project-gradle/ . The usage of shadowJar there is correct, but not required to get started.

Comment: True that I am trying to get into the gradle game and was unsure how to get stared with the commands.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this Yeoman generator:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-dropwizard-gradle

If you have npm installed.

The line `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` is sufficient, yes.

You can also search on github for examples, like this one:
https://github.com/kishaningithub/dropwizard-gradle

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. I looked it over but there seems to be a lot going on in the back.  the `build.gradle` also seems to have some funny dependencies. thanks again for the tipp